# I am getting AFHTTPClient Failed to call designated initializer

Tags: afnetworking

My code was ok until I downloaded the latest AFNetworking library from CocoaPods.

Now I am getting:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'AFHTTPClient Failed to call designated initializer. Invoke `initWithBaseURL:` instead.'
```

I didn't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling alloc - init. Call alloc - initWithBaseURL instead.